# Creating a TYPE that is an Array within a Function (or a predefined Array TYPE) in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, array, domain

I am researching migration of a major system from Oracle to PostgreSQL.  Getting into coding functions now, and am looking to see if there is a compatible object in PostgreSQL where, dynamically within a Function I can create a TYPE as an array.

The syntax in Oracle is:

```
TYPE VAR_STRING IS VARRAY(10) VARCHAR2(30);
```

This creates a 10 element array TYPE named VAR_STRING to hold 10 strings of 30 characters.

I am playing with PG 9.6, and even in the `Create Type` dialog, it is not obvious to me to make a pre-defined `TYPE` that can be an array.

Comment: Why play with Postgres 9.6? Start with current Postgres 12 (or even Postgres 13 Beta).

Comment: You typically don't need to create a type for that in Postgres (SQL or PL/pgSQL). It would be helpful to see the full code, I suspect there is a much more simple solution in Postgres

Comment: Right. Perhaps the Oracle code does a `BULK COLLECT`, which does not exist in PostgreSQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `varchar(30)[]`. Example:

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
   var_string varchar(30)[] := '{a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j}';
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', var_string;
END
$$;
```

(Assigning at declaration time is optional; defaults to `NULL`.)
(Lower case identifiers are advisable for Postgres - in contrast to Oracle.)

The [manual on array declaration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION).

Of course, the number of elements is not limited to 10 for the basic type. Do you even need that? And do you need to enforce a maximum string length of 30? Typically a plain text array `text[]` should do the job.

You *can* specify the size of the array:

```
varchar(30)[10]
```

But that's not effective beyond documentation. [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> However, the current implementation ignores any supplied array size
>   limits, i.e., the behavior is the same as for arrays of unspecified length.

To positively enforce a maximum of 10 elements, you could create a [**`DOMAIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) over the basic type with a `CHECK` constraint.

```
CREATE DOMAIN varchar30_arr_max_10_elem AS varchar(30)[]
CHECK(cardinality(VALUE) <= 10);
```

Then use `varchar30_arr_max_10_elem` like any other type.

Related:

- [Issues with PL/pgSQL code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643573/939860)

Aside: Why use the name `var_string` for an array? It's not a string.